# Why is the chi-square I get for VCD's assocstats() function different from descr's crosstab() function?

Tags: r, statistics

I am using the `descr` package so I can use `crosstab()` to make a table and return a chi square for two variables. However, I also need the phi coefficient, which VCD's `assocstats()` returns (I know it's a simple formula, but eh lazy). However, the chi-square for assocstats() is different than the chi-square for crosstab(), which will affect my phi coefficient value. Why is this happening (the difference is really small, but still)?

If it is relevant, I doing a test on 2 variables, each with 4 categories (4x4 table)

Comment: Unless you post data, code and output, this question would not seem to actually be about _coding_, now would it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ...And.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  ... and there's the option of flagging this to be moved to CrossValidated.com